# Proving union of 2 regular languages is regular

Tags: formal-languages, finite-automata

I have an exam tomorrow and the professor said that from the following two facts we should be able to show that the union of 2 regular languages is regular:

1. Given 2 regular languages, their intersection is regular
2. A compliment of a regular language is regular

I'm pretty confused on how I would get started with showing this. Can anybody please help me understand on how I would use those 2 facts to prove such a thing?

Comment: This should be covered in your favorite textbook. See also [tag:closure-properties], https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language#Closure_properties.

Comment: Welp... that wasn't too helpful

Comment: Agreed. These things were most likely covered in the lecture, so review your notes.

Answer (score 3):

Use De Morgan rule $A\cup B = \overline{\overline{A} \cap \overline{B}}$.

Also you could prove it using DFA for $L_1$ and $L_2$ without using complement and intersection. The latter is systematic and can be easily implemented in one of your favorite programming languages. In other words, if you have DFA for $L_1$ and $L_2$ then you can construct the third DFA accepting $L_1 \cup L_2$.

Answer (score 2):

You use the fact that each regular language has a corresponding regex, NFA and (total) DFA.

For the union you can do `regex_1|regex_2` where | is the choice operator. Or take the NFA of each and create a new NFA where the start has a $\epsilon$ transition to the start of each of the original NFAs

For the complement you take the total DFA (where every state has a transition for every character in $\Sigma$) and then set the new final states as $Q \setminus F$

Comment: That's not using other closure properties as the question asks for.